# PHP Date Parse into a new format

Tags: php

I have a function that prints out:

```
echo $post->EE_Event->primary_datetime()->start_date_and_time();
```

result:

```
21-02-15 08:00
```

But i want to display it as:

```
08:00 21st February, 2015
```

I need help with a function to grab the existing printed out date and reformat it.

I have tried a few snippets online, but nothing that worked.

Comment: Do we have another spawn of the help Dracula?

Comment: What "snippets" did you find online?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$yourDate = '21-02-15 08:00'; // $post->EE_Event->primary_datetime()->start_date_and_time()
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-m-y G:i', $yourDate);
echo $date->format('G:i dS F, Y');
```

Try it online:
http://ideone.com/a7EEK4

In PHP >= 5.3 we have excellent date API.
See more here:
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: Works a treat thanks @jakon i found the 3rd line and was already trying to make that work, but it was the createfromformat that i hadnt tried. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

PHP's [`DateTime`](http://php.net/DateTime) class has exactly what you need.  You want to use the [`createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to parse it in, then use [`format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to print it back out.

```
$myDate = $post->EE_Event->primary_datetime()->start_date_and_time();
$myDateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y G:i', $myDate);

echo $myDateObj->format('G:i jS F, Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date("G:i dS F, Y", strtotime($post->EE_Event->primary_datetime()->start_date_and_time()));
```